# How to detect language iPhone web app?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, detection

Is there a way to detect the language of your users (on an iPhone web app), but not by using the ip or the gps location ? I know it's very annoying when you go for example to turkey, and you're apps are in turkish… So… How can i really detect the language of the system ??

Is it possible in javascript ?

I should want if it's english, the web app uses eng.js for dutch dut.js and further…

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you can do a `window.navigator.language` in Javascript.

I suggest you name your files by using the ISO standard for languages; like 'en_US.js' for English (US) and 'nl_NL.js' for Dutch. That would make things easier when using `window.navigator.language`:

```
(function(){
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var lang = document.createElement('script');

    lang.type = 'text/javascript';
    lang.async = true;
    lang.src = '/languages/' + window.navigator.language + '.js';

    s.parentNode.insertBefore(lang,s);
})();
```

You should however do a check if the 'window.navigator.language.js'-file exists or not.

Comment: @eds1999 you're welcome :) Please mark it as an answer if this helped solve your problem.